# WCF with worker thread limit

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, com

I have written a .net wrapper around an old COM/OLE Server instance. It is a stateful wrapper that requires a few initialisation calls followed by a final 'go/calculate call'.

This final call creates a new instance of a class and then create a new thread using System.Threading.Thread that creates the COM instances and enables it to run separately to the IIS worker thread, with subsequent calls to check on status and ultimately get results.

Problem is, when I try and create more than 20 concurrent instances I get an out of memory exception. I have tried various tweaks - creating multiple worker threads doesn't help because of the stateful nature (I believe). I have tried many of these

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133738/Quick-Ways-to-Boost-Performance-and-Scalability-of

To no avail. In my stress tester I tried instantiating the wrapper class directly rather than via a WCF service and I can run > 150 instances before I start to run into problems.

Does anyone know of a way to increase the number of worker threads an IIS insatnce can spawn?

Comment: No - as I say I can make the call directly on the same box and get over 150 instances. It is only when the call is made as a service do I get the hard limit of 20.

Comment: Where is the OOM exception thrown? What component does that? What callstack? Is the server process 32 bit and maybe your other test process 64 bit?

Comment: The exception is thrown on creation 'Activator.CreateInstance(rtwbType)' it is a 64bit box, but the WCF service is 32bit as is the COM/OLE server it is instantiating. At the point the exception is thrown a new thread has been created already. The exception typically brings down the entire IIS worker process currently.

Comment: What's the private bytes value of the IIS worker at 19 instances? Let's make sure this is not about memory.

Comment: Ok, sounds sensible. How do I check? The limit is 0 i.e. no limit....

Comment: Not sure what limit you are talking about. Check the private bytes whatever way you like. This is not IIS specific.

Comment: OK I thought you were referring to the IIS private byte limit on threads. The PB for IIS is ~40MB and each COM instance ~20MB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may benefit from using a web garden. Set max worker processes in app pool settings to > 1.

They can help in situations like this to increase throughout , but ideally you should be looking at the code to identity and optimize bottlenecks.

https://serverfault.com/questions/81689/web-gardens-are-they-good-or-bad-or-what

Note the downsides are: in proc session state not maintained across app pools and each process will have it's own cache copy if you are using asp http cache.